# How do I calculate opposite / most distanced coordinates on the earth?

Tags: spherical-coordinates

If i get this coordinates:

City Coordinates: 43°52′0″N 18°25′0″E
φ Latitude °N, λ Longitude °E (of Map center):
(43.8562586, 18.413076300000057)

How do i determine most distant / opposite coordinates on the earth from those coordinates?

Answer (score 4):

For an oblate spheroid model (or a spherical model), you negate the latitude and add $180^\circ$ to the longitude.

Comment: Another question is: Does ellipsoid (as earth is not perfect sphere) has only one point B which is equally distant from point A in whatever direction it's measured? Obviously not?

Comment: No, even for an oblate spheroid.  Take point A on the equator.  It is shorter going over the poles than around the equator.  An ellipsoid (which has three distinct axes) will be worse.

Comment: at least, i can have a point with an equal distance (East or West) sides and (North or South) sides?

Comment: Yes for a spheroid. The equation I describe does that.  I think the same point that is halfway around any geodesic, which I believe are closed on a spheroid.

Comment: So, that is fair enough... "Find a point B, equally distant from east and west side from point A"
It would actually be one meridian not the point but the meridian.
And on that meridian, i would look for a point that is equally distant towards north and south to point A.

I'm wrong? Why?

Comment: That will get you exactly the point I described, and it will be the same distance around the geodesic either way by symmetry.  You're not wrong.  The reason I focus on geodesics is that is the way to measure distances on any path on a curved surface.  They are locally the shortest distance between two points.

Answer (score 1):

Antipodal point Coordinates: 43°52′0″ S, 180-18°25′0″ W.
φ Latitude °S, λ Longitude °W (of Map center):

Comment: Thank you for the term "Antipodal".